# Create a ext-js grid from a JSONObject

Tags: javascript, servlets, extjs, extjs4

I'm new in extjs and i try to create a grid using ext js from a JSONObject sent by a servlet.

Here is my client-side code : (assuming the JSONObject is sent)

```
protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    String nameSent = request.getParameter("name"); 
    String dobSent = request.getParameter("dob"); 
    String addrSent = request.getParameter("addr");
    System.out.println("Name : " +nameSent+ " - Dob : " +dobSent+ " - Addr : " +addrSent);

    JSONObject toSendBack = new JSONObject(); 
    toSendBack.put("nameSent", nameSent); 
    toSendBack.put("dobSent", dobSent); 
    toSendBack.put("addrSent", addrSent); 
    toSendBack.put("success",true);
    response.getWriter().print(toSendBack.toString());
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
}
```

So, i have 3 String, which i would to put into an extjs grid as soon as i click on "submit"

Here is my ext-js code : (at least, the mos important part)

```
var form = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        renderTo : 'form', 
        frame : true, 
        title : 'Subscription', 
        width : 250, 
        url : 'TestServlet', 
        method : 'POST', 

        fieldDefaults : {
            labelAlign : 'left', 
            labelWidth : 90, 
            anchor : '100%'
        },

        items : [{
            xtype : 'textfield', 
            fieldLabel : 'Name ', 
            name : 'name',
            allowBlank : false
        }, {
            xtype : 'datefield', 
            fieldLabel : 'Dob ', 
            name : 'dob'
        }, {
            xtype : 'textfield', 
            fieldLabel : 'Address ', 
            name : 'addr'
        }, {
            xtype : 'radiogroup', 
            columns : 1, 
            fieldLabel : 'Gender ',
            name : 'gender', 
            items : [{
                name : 'male',
                boxLabel : 'Male', 
                inputValue : 'male'
            }, {
                name : 'female', 
                boxLabel : 'Female',
                inputValue : 'female'
            }]
        }, {
            xtype : 'button', 
            text : 'Submit', 
            handler : function(){
                var dataToSend = this.up('form').getForm(); 
                dataToSend.submit(
                {
                    success:function(form,action)
                    {
                        alert("success");
                        var result=Ext.JSON.decode(action.response.responseText);
                        resultPanel.items.items[0].setValue(result.nameSent);
                    },
                    failure:function(form,action)
                    {
                        alert("failure");                           
                    }
                }
                ); 
            }
        }]
    });
```

Question is : I don't know how to create the grid, and the model to define it.

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I suggest you create a grid and corresponding store and later on once you get success load the store with the data and show the grid.
Below is a very simple example where in I am getting the system properties from java layer in the form of json 
Below is the json

```
{"OSArchitectire":"amd64","OSVersion":"6.1","JVMVersion":"1.7.0_51","JVMVendor":"Oracle Corporation","OSName":"Windows 7","JVMVendorURL":"http://java.oracle.com/"}
```

I am mapping with the store in the following way.

```
 success: function(response){

      var store =     Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                            fields: ['JVMVendor', 'JVMVersion', 'OSName'],
                            proxy: {
                                type: 'memory',
                                reader: {
                                    type: 'json'
                                }
                            }
                        }); 

                        store.loadRawData(Ext.decode(response.responseText));
                        var grid=  Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
                                title: 'Simpsons',
                                floating: true,
                                id:'gridStore',
                                store: store,
                                columns: [{
                                    header: 'Name',
                                    dataIndex: 'JVMVendor'
                                }, {
                                    header: 'Version',
                                    dataIndex: 'JVMVersion',
                                    flex: 1
                                }, {
                                    header: 'OsName',
                                    dataIndex: 'OSName'
                                }],
                                height: 200,
                                width: 400,
                            });

                        grid.show();
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you ! 

Now i do have a grid, but i can't populate it with the data i received.

What do i have to put in the dataIndex to get the right JSONPart ? 

My JSon is like that : {"dobSent":"07/08/2014","success":true,"addrSent":"sdf","nameSent":"namename"}

Comment: Map your dataIndex to your Json keys.Like doBsent , addrSent , nameSent .Your column look like {header:'Address Sent' , dataIndex:'addrSent',flex:1}  . Hope it helps you.

Comment: @sree This is not working for me..I get the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'loadRawData' of undefined.. Can you help me?

Comment: @user3604227 Did you check whether you are getting the json response to load the store  ?

Comment: @Sreek521 I am getting the json response,but when I add some new data by filling in a form and submitting, The  grid is not displaying the new record that has been added. Right now, in the onSubmitSuccess method,i have this.getBookStore().sync() and load() both..but it does not work..

Comment: @user3604227 Could you please provide code snippet of what you have written. And try reloading the store using store.reload().